# How do I pass an array of struct to a multiple functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, struct

I have three files. The struct to defined in the **header file**:

```
struct Person
    {
    string name;
    char gender;
    int age;
    };
```

The second file called **functions**, contains 2 function. A simple read from a text file:

```
/*PersonCountVal is a value from another function that counts 
how many records there are in the txt file for the 'for loop'.*/

void PersonFileRead(int PersonCountVal, Person *PersonRecord) 
{
    ifstream PersonFile;
    PersonFile.open("person.txt");

    if (!PersonFile)
    {
        cerr << "File can't be opened or not found! " << endl;
        
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    PersonFile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
    
//the value for PersonCountVal is 20 i.e there are 20 records in the text file
        for (int i = 0; i < PersonCountVal; i++) 
        {
            PersonFile >> 
            PersonRecord[i].name >> 
            PersonRecord[i].gender >> 
            PersonRecord[i].age >> 
        }
        PersonFile.close();
```

The second function, the print funtion is:

```
void PersonDetailPrint(int PersonCountVal , Person *PersonRecord)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < PersonCountVal; i++) 
    {
        cout << PersonRecord[i].name << "\t";
        cout << PersonRecord[i].gender << "\t";
        cout << PersonRecord[i].age << "\t";
    }
}
```

The third file , the **main file**, contains the call and other stuff.

```
Person PersonRec[PersonCount];
Person *pointerPersonRec[PersonCount] = &PersonRec[PersonCount];

//Function 1 
PersonFileRead(PersonCount, pointerPersonRec[PersonCount]);

//Function 2
PersonDetailPrint(PersonCount, pointerPersoRec[PersonCount]);
```

The **Function File** has:

```
#include "header.h"
```

And the **Main File** has:

```
#include "header.h"
#include "Functions.cpp"
```

The error I'm getting is:

> [Error] array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

My IDE is Dev-C++ 5.11.

I don't know if the entire thing is wrong or just the error part because I got some solutions from a few questions previously asked and answered on stack overflow and tried to combine them but it didn't work.

Comment: what do you excpet `Person *pointerPersonRec[PersonCount] = &PersonRec[PersonCount];` to do ? `PersonRec` is an array with `PersonCount` elements and `PersonRec[PersonCount]` is not an element in the array. Use `std::vector`

Comment: `Person *pointerPersonRec[PersonCount] = &PersonRec[PersonCount];` is wrong and might be removed. And use `PersonFileRead(PersonCount, PersonRec);`.

Comment: 1. Why do you need `pointerPersonRec` at all ? 2. In order to call the functions you can use e.g.: `PersonFileRead(PersonCount, PersonRec]);` (the array will decay into a pointer).

Comment: You don't need to create a separate pointer, an array automatically "decays" to a pointer in the call, like `PersonFileRead(PersonCount, PersonRec);`. And BTW, you "pointer" is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array. (But just don't bother with it).

Comment: Unrelated: Dev-cpp 5.11 comes with GCC 4.9.2, which is *ancient*. GCC 12 was released last month. You should really upgrade.

Comment: `#include "Functions.cpp"`  Source .cpp files should not be included.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. An extra thank you to @Jarod42 because your answer was the most easiest to follow.